# Is there a way for the consumer the get the n last messages with KafkaJS?

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, kafkajs

im new to Kafka and KafkaJS.

Im trying to find a way to get the last n messages sent to a topic, instead of getting all non-consumed messages of that topic.

For example, I have a producer that produces 1 message per second and let it wait for 5 seconds.

Then, when I start the consumer, the consumer gets all 5 messages.
( Only 1 consumer running, 1 group, 1 partition, same topic as producer ).

Is there a configuration on KafkaJS to get only the last n produced messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could poll a single record, or otherwise [list the offsets of the topic](https://kafka.js.org/docs/admin#fetch-topic-offsets) beforehand.

Then you can [`seek` a consumer](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#seek) to `high_offset - N` and start polling from there

Comment: I see, that could be a way, but I would need to create an admin for it. Is there no other way to do so from the consumer itself? I have also tried `await consumer.subscribe({  fromBeginning: false })` because the docs mention: `When fromBeginning is true, the group will use the earliest offset. If set to false, it will use the latest offset. The default is false.` But it doesn't work, the consumer still fetches all non-consumed messages from the beginning, instead of giving the last non-consumed message. Also, could you please give an example of polling a single record? Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating an adminclient for this purpose. You seem to misunderstand that the `fromBeginning` is only used for non-existing `group.id` values in the cluster. If there already is a group with committed offsets, it'll always used those stored values, regardless of your `fromBeginning` value

Comment: I see, thats awesome! thanks for the help :)